# Replace characters in an HTML document that match a regex, except those inside tags

Tags: regex, perl, sed, html-parsing

I want to replace all characters matching a pattern in a HTML document except those inside HTML tags. How do you do this with a regex using Perl or sed?

Example: replace all "a" with "b" but not if "a" is in an HTML tag like `<a href="aaa">`.

Comment: Use an html parser. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/372239

Comment: You *really must* use an HTML parser. You may find something that you *think* works, but it will break later on and you will have *no idea* where to look to find the bug.

Comment: With a sed, you have too much exception to deal that it would be bery hard to manage (and understand).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments a HTML parser is the ideal solution for your problem, however if you do for whatever reason want to use a regex, the following will work:

```
a(?![^<]*>)
```

[Working example on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37dl9) and [the same for input.](http://regexr.com?37dli)

**[And in Perl](http://codepad.org/aQ3tGqsW)**:

```
$var = "salut <a href='a.html'></a> ah ha <a href='about.asp' /> animal";
#        ^     ^       ^         ^  ^   ^  ^       ^     ^       ^   ^
$var =~ s/a(?![^<]*>)/b/g;
print $var;
```

**Output:**

```
sblut <a href='a.html'></a> bh hb <a href='about.asp' /> bnimbl
 ^                          ^   ^                        ^   ^
```

Comment: Might I direct you to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @VectorGorgoth Thanks for the downvote. This answer is correct given the OP asked for a regex. I have seen that link posted many times, I do not need reminding. For simple applications I see no reason not to use a regex, the question does not concern the structure of the HTML. If the question was: I want to replace all `A`s in a sentence but only when not enclosed in brackets `"hallo [not this a] but this a"` would you still have downvoted me? Because the problem being solved is exactly the same. Feel free to post a working solution that uses a HTML parser and I will delete this answer.

Comment: Using regexes to parse HTML is dangerous and stupid. You'll notice all the replies to the question in the comments amount to, "DON'T USE REGEXES".

Comment: @VectorGorgoth I have a provided a solution to a problem. If you ever have this problem yourself I advise you use a HTML parser, if the OP wants a quick and dirty 1 liner (literally 17 characters), my solution 100% fulfils his specified needs. I have gone ahead and added a disclaimer to the top of my post, I hope this satisfies you.

Comment: Okay, okay. Undownvoted. I still think it's better to avoid giving "quick and dirty" solutions because in my experience NO "one-off" solution has any guarantee of remaining that way.

Answer (score 0):

Resurrecting this ancient question because it had a simple solution that wasn't mentioned.

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html, here is a simple way to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$regex = '<[^>]*|(a)';
$subject = 'aig arother <a href="aaa">';
($replaced = $subject) =~ s/$regex/
if (defined $1)  {"b";} else {$&;} /eg;
print $replaced . "\n";
```

See this [live demo](http://ideone.com/BV4C7F)

**Reference**

[How to match pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)

[How to match a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)